# what's the difference between giving dyndns(hostname) to the router compared to giving it to a NAS in the network?

Tags: networking, home-networking, nas, dynamic-dns

I have a router and a few computers,iphones and stuff on my network. recently I acquired a NAS device(synology USB station 2). I understand that in order to access it from ouside, a hostname thing will help...so somethin like dyndns. I was wondering what is the difference and advantages/disadvantages between setting up dyndns on the router level as opposed to setting it up on the NAS level. I guess one thing is by setting it up at a router level, I also get to connect to my computers...but that being said, none of my computers are acting as servers, so in my case does that mean dyndns at NAS level is the way to go?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't matter which computer or device is running the update client, as all it does is inform the dynamic DNS service of your current public IP address.  Any machine on your NATted LAN will be able to be accessed through the domain name from the dynamic DNS service (firewall settings and port forwarding permitting).

I think it is better to run it on the router, as it will never be turned off, or if it has been, or if it hangs/crashes, nothing would be available behind it anyway.  If your NAS device crashes or is turned off, you will not be able to access anything else on your LAN if your dynamic public IP address changes.